# C passing in cat return value

Tags: c, linux, cat

I want to know how to pass a value into a program like:
cat somefile | myprog

somefile:
hello

$cat somefile | myprog

>hello

this is what I tried.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  printf("%s", argv[1]);
  return 0;
}
```

I doubt it's complicated but I Just don't know how.

P.S my keyboard is boarderline broken if some chars are a little off.

Comment: `cat` does not have a "return value", but outputs to standard output. You can pipe this to your application, *but it goes to standard input*. Also, decide which language you are using. IO code is generally different between C and C++ (*and C# which you originally tagged*).

Comment: @crashmstr sorry it was for C i thought the title would be clear enough sorry for misleading tags.

Comment: @crashmstr Hmmm... seems to me `cat` does have a return value... e.g. `cat /tmp/nonexistent 2>> /dev/null; echo $?` gives me `1`... Granted, the things `cat` outputs use the processes standard output channel (whether that's `stdout` or `cout` or ...) as you state, though...

Comment: @twalberg yes, I know that `cat` does indeed have a return value (all programs that exit normally should have one). But in this case, the question has nothing to do with its return value. Hence my over-simplification of such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want your example `cat foo | bar` to work, you need to read data from standard input, e.g.:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int ch;
  while ( (ch = getchar()) != EOF )
    putchar(ch);
}
```

This program just echoes everything coming form standard input to standard output, so

```
$ cat somefile | myprog
```

will then print `hello`.  You don't have to parse anything from `argv`, because the surrounding shell will already have parsed that for you and discerned between stuff like program arguments and pipes.

Comment: `ch` should be declared as an `int`.

Comment: @csl sweet thanks! and thanks for the argv explination aswell very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You just have to read from the standard input of your program.

Try reading a line using `cin` or `scanf`.

For example for reading a single line and printing it out using `cin`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::string s;
   std::getline(std::cin, s);
   std::cout << s << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: That won't read a single line, but a white-space delimited string. You need `getline` to read a line.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a few options of what you might want here:

- You want to pass the filename 'somefile' to your program.

  `$ myprog somefile`
  `argv` is the **parameter** array - so you can access 'somefile' at `argv[1]`
- `somefile` contains a list of parameters like "hello world"

  `$ cat somefile | xargs myprog`

  Now 'hello' and 'world' will be at `argv[1]` and `argv[2]` respectively. It's analogous to invoking your program as `myprog hello world`.
- You want to read the contents of the pipe (the file contents) inside your file.

  As others have said, you're just reading from stdin. Pipe effectively attaches the     stdout of the previous command to the stdin of the following command.

Comment: woah not quite what I wanted but very usfull and it worked great. I've never really used xargs i'll have to look into it